# Customize Clonezilla to simplify choices

Tags: configuration, clonezilla

I am using Clonezilla in a non-profit organization. I wrote a usage guideline, but it needs 38 steps.

Now I wonder whether I could customize my Clonezilla USB Stick so that it does not provide all the options.

E.g. I could get rid of

- the language selection. It's totally fine if it's always English
- the keymap choice. It should just select "keep the default" ("don't touch the keymap" on older versions)
- the operation mode choice. We always want "device-image".
- the storage selection. We always need "local_dev".

What would I need to do to configure Clonezilla to get rid of these choices?

Answer (score 1):

Clonezilla calls that '[preseeding](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/05_Preseed_options_to_do_job_after_booting)' as described in that web link. As you pick options, Clonezilla shows the preseed commands in [green-on-black as shown here](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live/doc/02_Restore_disk_image/images/ocs-10-img-restore-command-prompt.png).

For example, the preseeding command should include a language selection command `locales=en_US.UTF-8` and a specification for no special keyboard layout with `keyboard-layouts=NONE` in syslinux.cfg or isolinux.cfg as appropriate.

Comment: Definitely the term I was looking for. I'll look into that and accept when I successfully applied an option. This may take two days.